# Jquery Mobile too slow

Tags: android, spring, performance, jquery-mobile

I wrote a web-app with the jquery mobile framework. Unfortunately too often it takes too long until the page is completely loaded (average time around 4-6 secs) what makes the usability horrible.

Using destop browsers there's almost no waiting time. Newer phones or tablets are acceptable refering to speed.

Server-sided processing (like db queries) running fast using c3p0 connection pooling. So I exclude that this could be the problem why page shows delayed.
Sometimes it also takes too long until success-method of an ajax-call is triggered.

Do you have any suggestions what I can do to get a better performance? I'm using a "multipage" template which means (if I'm not wrong) that request redirected from Spring-Controller calls suited jsp (Resolver) as view to open. All logic coming from spring controller attributes are integrated in jstl-tags in the jqm-page. I don't know if this is a good approch, but corresponds to classic web development.

In case I won't get a better performance, is it recommendable to develop a native app for android and ios if the app is often used? I read that web apps are a solution for websites that are now and then visited by their users but not in steady use by them. Does maybe an hybrid approach cause a better preformance?

Comment: Try preloading the pages

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-cache.html):

If you're using a single page template, but would prefer to lazy load in a few key pages in the background to avoid seeing the Ajax loader, we recommend using the pre-fetch feature instead of moving to a multi-page template. To pre-fetch a page, simply add the data-prefetch attribute to any link and jQuery Mobile will lazy load this page in the background after the primary page has loaded. Here's an example:

```
<a href="foo/bar/baz" data-prefetch>link text</a>
```